# Persistent Http Connections Android

Tags: android, http, https, android-networking

I want to make a persistent http connection in my android application. Since the backend responses are configured for **Keep-Alive**.

I would like to know how to make persistent http connections in Android in order to avoid handshake request everytime.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Set the header to include a keep-alive request.

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) mURL.openConnection();
conn.setRequestProperty("Connection","Keep-Alive");
```